# How to import tables from a specific oracle schema using sqoop?

Tags: oracle, sqoop

I am trying to import all the oracle tables from a specific schema using Sqoop, Even though I specify the -- --schema parameter it's still redirecting me to the default schema. After my research I think  oracle doesn't support this parameter. Below is my code

```
sqoop import-all-tables --connect "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(url)" -username testUser --password-file /user/hadoop/oracle_pwd.password --autoreset-to-one-mapper --warehouse-dir s3://bucket/ADW_IMPORT/ -- --schema ADW -m 32
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put schema in connect parameter i.e --connect "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(url)"/SchemaName.

Comment: It's throwing error  `18/01/09 08:58:23 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.OracleManager.listTables(OracleManager.java:759)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ListTablesTool.run(ListTablesTool.java:49)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)`

Comment: yes . . it's working fine with specifing the schema before in the table argument like TESTSCHEMA.TESTTABLE